# How to add time in geoserver layer with gsconfig

Tags: python, raster, geoserver, vector, time

Find below the code I use to add a raster to geoserver through python3 with gsconfig-py3 (1.0.7)

### What I do

```
from geoserver import catalog
from geoserver.util import shapefile_and_friends
from geoserver.support import DimensionInfo

ws_name = "hiphen_iota"
store_name = "fda_2017_site03_ndvi_20170809"
style_tif_name = "hiphen_iota:ndvi_fda"

layer_path = 'U:/jeremy/FDA/Ortho_Indice/NDVI_Site03_20170809.tif'
layer_time = "2017-08-09T12:00:00.0Z"
###
# connect remotely to geoserver
cat = catalog.Catalog("http://##############:8080/geoserver/rest/")
# create / connect a new workspace
#ws = cat.create_workspace('python_test')
ws = cat.get_workspace(ws_name)
# create a new store with a shapefile
ft = cat.create_coveragestore(store_name, workspace=ws, data=layer_path )
# add a style
ft = cat.get_layer(store_name)
ft.default_style = cat.get_style(style_tif_name)
cat.save(ft)
```

Then I activate time dimension:

```
# add time dimension
timeInfo = DimensionInfo("time", "true", "LIST", None, "ISO8601", None)
ft.metadata = ({'time': timeInfo})
```

Afterwards, I found nowhere how to set time for my layer, I expect something like this:

### What I want

```
ft = cat.get_layer(store_name)
ft.set_time("2017-08-09T12:00:00.0Z")
cat.save(ft)
```

My final purpose is to automatically add raster/layer to geoserver and use this: [leaflet time dimension](http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found my answer with this tutorial : [geoserver tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html)

We have to put timestamp in the name of the raster and the time dimension is build barely automatically :)